# Apache Spark: ERROR Executor -> Iterator

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run example from here ([Learning Spark book](https://github.com/153485062/learning-spark/blob/master/mini-complete-example/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/mini/java/WordCount.java)), but I'm getting following error:

```
16/10/07 01:15:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
```

I start the job with:
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class 
`com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount ./target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar ./README.md ./wordcounts`

Please ideas, why is this happening?

Full log:

```
mini-complete-example$ $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount ./target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar ./README.md ./wordcounts
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/10/07 01:15:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/10/07 01:15:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: eDS
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: eDS
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(eDS); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(eDS); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 63851.
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/yw/zl5hc321387g3sz2fg3l01980000gq/T/blockmgr-0fb2af5a-8662-4d78-88c8-8e0608f35ff3
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.17:4040
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/eDS/dev/learning-spark/mini-complete-example/./target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar at spark://192.168.1.17:63851/jars/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar with timestamp 1475795724857
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 63852.
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.17:63852
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.17, 63852)
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.17:63852 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.17, 63852)
16/10/07 01:15:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.17, 63852)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 145.5 KB, free 366.2 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 16.3 KB, free 366.1 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.17:63852 (size: 16.3 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at WordCount.java:31
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: saveAsTextFile at WordCount.java:46
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 3 (mapToPair at WordCount.java:39)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (saveAsTextFile at WordCount.java:46) with 2 output partitions
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (saveAsTextFile at WordCount.java:46)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at mapToPair at WordCount.java:39), which has no missing parents
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.9 KB, free 366.1 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.7 KB, free 366.1 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.17:63852 (size: 2.7 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at mapToPair at WordCount.java:39)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5479 bytes)
16/10/07 01:15:25 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5479 bytes)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://192.168.1.17:63851/jars/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar with timestamp 1475795724857
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.1.17:63851 after 73 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://192.168.1.17:63851/jars/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar to /private/var/folders/yw/zl5hc321387g3sz2fg3l01980000gq/T/spark-5adda737-293c-483e-bdbe-f8fa7c171211/userFiles-2a2cf77d-5794-4006-a125-5df94550cbf8/fetchFileTemp6160431711224595115.tmp
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Executor: Adding file:/private/var/folders/yw/zl5hc321387g3sz2fg3l01980000gq/T/spark-5adda737-293c-483e-bdbe-f8fa7c171211/userFiles-2a2cf77d-5794-4006-a125-5df94550cbf8/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar to class loader
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/eDS/dev/learning-spark/mini-complete-example/README.md:66+66
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/eDS/dev/learning-spark/mini-complete-example/README.md:0+66
16/10/07 01:15:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 1385 bytes result sent to driver
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 307 ms on localhost (1/2)
16/10/07 01:15:26 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/10/07 01:15:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/10/07 01:15:26 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.17:4040
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (mapToPair at WordCount.java:39) failed in 0.364 s
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: saveAsTextFile at WordCount.java:46, took 0.448155 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:955)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1440)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/07 01:15:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(0,1475795726327,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.WordCount$1.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:))
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/07 01:15:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yw/zl5hc321387g3sz2fg3l01980000gq/T/spark-5adda737-293c-483e-bdbe-f8fa7c171211
mini-complete-example$
```

Comment: Where are you executing this ? in local ? which version of spark installed ?

Comment: have you downloaded the jar file to this location ? /target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar

Comment: sorry, yes locally. Version Spark 2.0.0 built for Hadoop 2.7.2.

Comment: did you check if the jar file is available from the location you are running ?

Comment: seeing the same problem (running the same example from here: https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/tree/master/mini-complete-example

As for the question above -  yes the jar file is present (otherwise, there would've been a different exception in there)

Comment: OK, so reading up on what that exception means, I would have to guess we must be using a different version of.. something. Java or Scala - the one installed on our machines doesn't match... something. I don't really know if this is anywhere close to truth, because we've built our code ourselves using mvn compile and whatnot. However, since the error seems to be arising somewhere inside the Spark's own code, I would imagine there are some incompatibility there? Just wild guesses, I'm not a JVM expert by any stretch of imagination. But inside pom.xml, it's mentioning java 1.6...

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error like :

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)

and

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ...

First, checking the spark version in following path :

> %SPARK_HOME%/jars/spark-core_x.xx-y.y.y.jar

And modify the `pom.xml` file as shown below :

```
<dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_x.xx</artifactId>
    <version>y.y.y</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope to help for stater like me.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because the version of the spark binaries in $SPARK_HOME is not the same as the version in your pom. If you're following the `pom.xml` as mentioned in the book, the dependency you'd end up adding is

```
<dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

which is version 1.2.0, while your $SPARK_HOME has binaries of version 2.0.0